# Embedding Google Map changes website font

Tags: google-maps, fonts, embed

I'm creating a contact page, and on that page I would like to have a map that points to my location.

The problem is that, once I embed the map, the font on the page changes (see for yourself by navigating through other pages of this domain). The embedding has 2 parts to it:


CODE BETWEEN THE HEAD TAGS

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
   <style>#gmap_canvas img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important}</style>
```

CODE BETWEEN THE BODY TAGS

```
 <div style="overflow:hidden;height:400px;width:450px;">
             <div id="gmap_canvas" style="height:400px;width:450px;"></div>
             </div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function init_map(){
    var myOptions = {
        zoom:11,
        center:new google.maps.LatLng(46.0475235,20.096552599999995),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN};
        
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas"), myOptions);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(46.0475235, 20.096552599999995)});
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content:"<b>MEGA d.o.o.</b><br/>Nenada Valceva 39<br/>23330 Novi Knezevac" });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", 
        function(){infowindow.open(map,marker);
    })
   ;}
    
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
  </script>
```

By adding and removing the code, I found out that the script in the second part causes the problem. However, I don't have any idea how to correct this, and make the page display in nice, neat font, like the rest of 'em.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your page you use the Webfont "Roboto", which will be loaded from:

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300&amp;subset=latin-ext
```

The maps-API also loads this font, but with different settings:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700
```

...which will extend the `@font-face`'s loaded from the first stylesheet.

For a unique Layout you have these options:

- use another font in your page
- use the same stylesheet as the maps-API does to load the font
- remove the stylesheet which has been loaded by the maps-API:

  ```
  //add this after the creation of the google.maps.Map
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map,'idle',function(){
    var font=document.querySelector('link[href$="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700"]');
    if(font){
      font.parentNode.removeChild(font);
    }
  });
  ```

---

**Demo:**

```js
function initialize() {

        return new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
          zoom: 0,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0)
        });

      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {

        var btn = document.getElementById('foo');
        btn.innerHTML = 'click here to load the map<br/>(observe the changes in the appereance of the text above )';
        google.maps.event.addDomListenerOnce(btn, 'click', function() {
          btn.innerHTML = 'loading map, please wait';
          var map = initialize();
          google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
            btn.innerHTML = 'you may have noticed some changes in the appereance of the text above.<br/>' +
              'click again to remove the stylesheet loaded by the maps-API ';
            google.maps.event.addDomListenerOnce(btn, 'click', function() {
              var font = document.querySelector('link[href$="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700"]');
              if (font) {
                font.parentNode.removeChild(font);
                btn.innerHTML = 'the stylesheet has been removed,<br/> the text above should be displayed correctly again';
              } else {
                btn.innerHTML = 'the stylesheet can\'t be localized';
              }
            });
          });
        });
      });
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  font-family: Roboto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300&amp;subset=latin-ext" />
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<h1>test-text</h1>
<button type="button" id="foo"></button>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to solve the problem... I feel like I'm doing something wrong... could you tell me exactly where to put those lines of code, regarding my own code... Sorry, JS isn't my strong-suit. The map is a real speed killer isn't it?

Comment: Put it directly after `map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas"), myOptions);` Note: I've modified the code, use the updated code(works regardless of the protocol in which the maps-API will be loaded). Related to the speed: the speed-killer isn't the map, there are 2 images in your page( http://www.mega.co.rs/WebStore/inventory_images/262.jpg , http://www.mega.co.rs/WebStore/inventory_images/4.jpg) with a total filesize of 7MB...reduce the filesize.

Comment: I copied the code and it causes font change 2 times while loading sometimes.